# How to close the FTPclient connection using FtpClientCS.dll in c#?

Tags: c#, ftp

A program is using FtpClientCS.dll to connect ftp.
When failed to connect, the program must be restarted. Is there any function for closing the connection with this dll? Or is there anything I can do to close the connection here? The dll cannot be replaced due to heavy usage of many programs(basically Windows services).

```
public static FTPclient GetFTPClient(int retry)
        {
            FTPclient ftpClient = null;
            Library.WriteErrorLog("Trying to connect remote server");

            try
            {
                ftpClient = new FTPclient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPHost"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUserPassword"]);
                ftpClient.UsePassive = true;
                FTPdirectory ftpDirectory = ftpClient.ListDirectoryDetail(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPFolderUploadPath"]);
                Library.WriteErrorLog("FTP Connected");
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ftpClient = null;
                Library.WriteErrorLog("Unable to connect remote server. Retrying to connect.. " + ex.Message);
                Library.WriteErrorLog("Retry time : " + retry);
            }

            return ftpClient;

        }
```

Comment: Googling "FtpClientCS.dll" yields hardly any relevant results. I suggest you switch to some more widely used FPT implementation.

Comment: Yes. It seems to be. More than twenty five programs are there including Windows Services to change. Anyway, thank you :)